# Как сделать текст равномерным по количеству слов в строчках?

Tags: css

Подскажите , у меня есть контейнер , внутри которого есть текст , при уменьшении размеров страницы , может произойти такое , что допустим на первой строчке будет 6 слов, а на второй будет 2 , то есть я не хочу ставить после слова которого мне нужно в html тег br , чтобы оно его перенесло на другую строчку, хотел бы узнать , можно ли как-то при помощи css сделать чтобы когда слова переносились на другие строчки , чтобы кол-во слов в них было приблизно одинаковое ?

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 176px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 120%; 
  letter-spacing: -1.2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

Comment: Нативных средств для решения задачи насколько я ее понял нет, судя по всему `text-align: justify;` Вас не устраивает.

Comment: Да , не сильно устраивает

Comment: А если к примеру первые три слова длинные а следующие три слова короткие все равно нужно по 3 в строку ?

Comment: условно хотелось , чтобы текст кол-во слов в строчке было приблизно одинаковым , а не как сейчас 6 в первой строчке, а во второй 2 слова

Comment: Это я понял, но я не понял что на счет того когда слова будут явно короче предыдущих, просто есть один вариант (делать паддинг определенного размера) но там нужно еще маленькую функцию прикрутить, поэтому важно четко понять как должен вести себя алгоритм при таких обстоятельствах условно говоря если слова будут такие "Неограниченное возможностями творчество, искра внутри горит" слово "творчество" все равно в первой строке должно быть?

Comment: Я вас понял , хотелось бы ,чтобы когда слова были короче предыдущих , то делать так , чтобы в нижней строчке было больше слов , чтобы можно так сказать ширина не очень сильно была разной у строчек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `text-wrap: balance;`, но у него не очень [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/css-text-wrap-balance#:%7E:text=Allows%20multiple%20lines%20of%20text,more%20readable%20and%20visually%20appealing.) на данный момент.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 176px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 120%;
  letter-spacing: -1.2px;
  text-wrap: balance;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам не надо фиксировать размеры страницы. Перенос строк, что б они смотрелись нормально можно реализовывать через свойство `text-align: justify;` или через [line-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-break)
По вашему примеру не понятно, что именно и когда вам надо переносить. Если вы для
`.container` браузер сам нормально перестроит ваш контент.

Comment: text-align: justify не сильно то , вот когда я нажимаю выполнить код , у меня в первом ряду 6 слов , а во втором 2 слова , я хотел бы чтобы и там и там приблизно было одинаковое кол-во слов , то еесть с верху там допустим 4 и с низу 4